# Single page application losing custom headers after a refresh

Tags: python, angularjs, single-page-application, custom-headers

I am building a single page web application (angularjs + python) where a user first needs to login with a username and password. After the user gets authenticated, a new custom header with a token is created and sent everytime this application makes calls to the python api.

One thing I noticed though, is that if I refresh the page (with F5 or Ctrl+F5) then the browser loses this custom header, so it is not sent anymore to the api.
Is there a way to keep the custom headers even after a refresh of the page?

Comment: You could use a cookie to store it... or just request new one, since you're probably keep it in server session.

Comment: That depends how you build your frontend code. If it contains only static files that are send to the client and the server acts only as an API then no. Otherwise you can build the frontend code on the server with the custom header present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the token in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`. In your application startup (config or run) look for this information and set your header.

Perhaps if your user selects "remember me" when they log-in; save the token in local storage otherwise keep it in session storage.

Comment: Great idea. Thank you. I will investigate about the sessionStorage which is perhaps what I will use for storing the token.